# Can I use the SQLite as a db storage for cloud-based websites?

Tags: sqlite, cloud

Has anyone ever launched cloud-based apps / websites that use a local SQLite DB as the primary data source?

Are there any warnings about this?

My environment:

- C# 3.0 app
- currently uses a sql server 2008 db
- current db size 30 mb-

Comment: What benefits do you see in SQLite?

Comment: I just need some thing that can work in the cloud and is free. SQL Azure will be expensive if I have 10,000 sites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expect a lot of traffic, you really shouldn't. SQLite is meant to be used as a lightweight SQL database, and is not meant for highly concurrent access (since it locks the **whole** database file) which could be an important requirement in this case.

Read:
[Appropriate uses for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: Agreed. SQLite is *awesome* for low-concurrency, but it simply doesn't provide the find-grained locking that more heavyweight DBs (Postgres, MySQL, etc) can provide, so high concurrency gets very tricky.

Comment: thanks! I may need to look into MySQL and see if they have a cloud ready version

Comment: SQLite supports unlimited readers at the same time but only one writer at a time. If the cloud database can be partitioned into smaller databases like  one sqlite database for each company then may be it might work since each company will have limited users at the same time trying to write to the database. But this is just an idea that came to my mind.