# Cloud Base Sqlite Database in Livecode

Tags: sqlite, livecode

I am working on a Livecode Aapplication. In this I need to use cloud base sqlite database. But I have not much knowledge about cloud base sqlite and how to implement it with Livecode Application. Could anyone explain to me, what is it and how can I use cloud base sqlite into Livecode?

Thanks

Comment: One of my client give me this task as i have to use cloud base sqlite in livecode application.I am not in communication with him right now.So i just wanted ,is there somebody who knows about this.I think he wants to have a database that will be common for all devices in which that application will run instead seperate for each device.

Comment: The I suggest that you ask him and do some research (e.g. google for "cloud base sqlite") and enhance your question....You can edit a question and thus improve the quality of the question.

Comment: okay i will .But can u please let me know if i create a sqlite database in application.Would it be shared by all devices who will download it or it will be works separately for every device?

Answer (score 1):

An SQLite database is just a file which resides in the file system of the device. So each device will have its own database with its own data. If you want to store data in the cloud you have to do something on the server side.

If you want to have a solution on the server you might want to go for a PHP script. PHP has sqlite access built in. However you can use other scripting languages as well.

Or on another line something like https://cloudant.com/ . But there the data is not stored in relational tables but as JSON objects. Access is as well through the http protocol (restful).

**Related question**
See also here [How to retrieve data from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820502/1669111)

**Suggestion** 
Please do not forget to use the search box of this web site. E.g. by searching for

```
sqlite cloud
```

you get

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sqlite+cloud

which has as the first answer

[A: Can I use the SQLite as a db storage for cloud-based websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833162/can-i-use-the-sqlite-as-a-db-storage-for-cloud-based-websites/3833191#3833191)

So your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: is there any way to put sqlite db file on cloud(web) and give path of that web location instead of file system in livecode? may be this is a silly question.

Comment: http://lessons.runrev.com/s/lessons/m/4071/l/7003-connecting-to-a-mysql-database...In this mysql database is accessible through the url,username and password from a web.There is no any Json parsing over there.Is it possible in the case of Sqlite?

Comment: Rohit, I suggest that you edit the question and replace the content of the question with this your last comment and make sure you have all the three tags - livecode, sqlite, mysql